# Unable to add card in Stripe iOS Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe SDK to make payments in iOS app developed in Swift 4. But the loading bar is stuck when clicked on "add card":
[image]

These are the sandbox credit card credentials. I am using **STPAddCardViewController**

```
let config = STPPaymentConfiguration()
config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .none
let viewController = STPAddCardViewController(configuration: config, theme: .default())
viewController.delegate = self
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have also set the publishable key in **AppDelegate.swift** in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** function:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    Terminal.setTokenProvider(StripeAPIClient())
    Stripe.setDefaultPublishableKey("pk_test_******")
    STPPaymentConfiguration.shared().publishableKey = "pk_test_*****"

    return true
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What sort of errors are you getting from the SDK or API, if any? I don't see a suggestion of setting the PK on the `STPPaymentConfiguration` like that in the guide. Are you following along from here? https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem. I commented this line:
STPPaymentConfiguration.shared().publishableKey = "pk_test_*****"
And now it is working fine.